# delete multiple database entries using ruby console

Tags: ruby

I have a database that was populated using a rails system. I am trying to go back and delete a list of id's from one of the tables. I am currently deleting a single entry using the following command.

```
Item.find(1).destroy
```

I would like to be able to delete a series of id's with a single command. (ie. 1,6,5,8,12,14)

```
Item.find(1,6,5,8,12,14).destroy
```

I know that this doesn't work but thats the idea of what I'd like to do. I am fairly new to ruby and just trying to determine the simplest way to proceed.

Comment: Do you need to just delete the records (in which case delete_all would be best), or destroy dependent associations and invoke callbacks (destroy_all)?

Comment: This is one of those times I'd drop into the console for the database and issue `delete from items where id in (1,6,5,8,12,14);`. It's important, and good, to know what ActiveRecord is doing behind the scenes, and how to do basic DBA tasks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to fetch the Items manually when Rails can do it for you:

```
Item.destroy_all(id: [1, 6, 5, 8, 12, 14])
```

or, as @ShankyMunjal posted, if you can use just ids, you can go with:

```
Item.destroy([1, 6, 5, 8, 12, 14])
```

Comment: Ah yes, indeed there is such method.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
[1,6,5,8,12,14].each {|iid| Item.find(iid).destroy }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Item.destroy( [1,6,5,8,12,14] )
```